# ¿Como poder imprimir un json cuando los key tienen el mismo nombre?

Tags: javascript, json

como pone en el titulo tengo un JSON a traves de xampp en el que hago un programa que crea el ***key*** a traves del nombre del campo ***porfesores*** y el resto de datos los creo como un objeto JSON, todo eso lo parseo y lo guardo en un ***sessionStorage*** mediante un ***for*** y lo imprime correctamente.
El problema surge cuando un profesor con un mismo nombre tiene varias asginaturas a su cargo y solo me imprime la primera asignatura que pilla, esto se debe a que a la hora de guardarlo el ***key*** no puede repetirse y no se como hacer para que se guarden y pueda mostrar todas las asignaturas que tienen a su cargo cada profesor. Dicho esto paso todo el codigo con el JSON incluido.

JSON:

```
 <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$json = '{
    "cursos": [
        {
            "id": "01",
            "materia": "Desarrollo Aplicaciones Web en Cliente",
            "nivel": "2º DAW",
            "profesor": "MariAngeles"
        },
        {
            "id": "02",
            "materia": "Lenguaje de Marcas",
            "nivel": "2º DAW",
            "profesor": "MariAngeles"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "03",
            "materia": "Servidor",
            "nivel": "2º DAW",
            "profesor": "Peligros"
        },
        {
            "id": "04",
            "materia": "Interfaces",
            "nivel": "2º DAW",
            "profesor": "Paco"
        },
        {
            "id": "05",
            "materia": "Entornos",
            "nivel": "1º DAW",
            "profesor": "Peligros"
        }
    ] 
}';
echo $json;
?>
```

html:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="mostrar datos">
    <div id="mostrar"></div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = mostrar;

}

function mostrar() {
    debugger;
    var profesor = prompt('Introduce el nombre para ver su asignatura ');
    var exist = false;
    var datofiltrado = null;
    for (let index = 0; index < sessionStorage.length && !exist; index++) {
        var key = sessionStorage.key(index);
        if (key === profesor) {
            exist=true;
            var cursos = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
            console.log(cursos);
            datofiltrado = JSON.parse(cursos);
            console.log(datofiltrado.materia);
        }
       
    }
    if (!exist) {
        alert("No has insertado ningun profesor, o profesor equivocado");
    } else {

        var content = document.getElementById('mostrar');
        content.innerHTML = '';

        var divprofesor = document.createElement('div');
        var txtprofesor = document.createTextNode('Asignarua: ' + datofiltrado.materia);

    
        divprofesor.appendChild(txtprofesor);

        content.appendChild(divprofesor);
    
        
    }
}

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest; //esto evalua los campos
debugger;


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var myjson = JSON.parse(this.responseText) //igual que el de abajo

        //var myjson = eval('('+this.responseText+')');//transforma el contenido que detecta
        debugger;
        console.log(myjson);

        var cursos = myjson.cursos;
        console.log(cursos.length);
     
        for (let index = 0; index < cursos.length; index++) {
           
            var profesor = cursos[index].profesor;//es una cadena de texto, y es el key
            console.log(profesor);
            var curso = {//objeto tipo json
                id: cursos[index].id,
                materia: cursos[index].materia,
                nivel: cursos[index].nivel
            }

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(curso);

            sessionStorage.setItem(profesor, jsonData);
        }

    } else if (this.readyState == 4 && (this.status == 404 || this.status != 200)) { //TODO LO QUE SEA DIFERENTE A 200 ES UN ERROR
        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        var txt_h1 = document.createTextNode(this.status + " - " + this.statusText);
        h1.appendChild(txt_h1);

        document.body.appendChild(h1);
    }


}


xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:90/dwec/EjemploCursos.php");
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que sería mas simple guardar todo el JSON en `sessionStorage` en una única clave y al llamar a `mostrar` recien recorrerlo e ir agregando los que coincidan directamente los elementos al `contect`. Si te parece bien, puedo crearte una respuesta

Comment: @Marcos, por desgracia las claves del JSON tienen que ser el nombre de los profesores si o si, no hay otra manera de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos crear un objeto `profesores` el cual usaremos almacenar los nombre de los profesores y sus cursos.

Al recorrer los `cursos`, verificamos si el nombre del profesor esta en `profesores` y si no esta lo inicializamos como un arreglo donde iremos agregando los distintos `cursos`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
let profesores = {}; // hashmap
for (let index = 0; index < cursos.length; index++) {

  var profesor = cursos[index].profesor;

  // Si aún no existe
  if (!profesores[profesor]) {
    // Inicializamos como un arreglo
    profesores[profesor] = [];
  }

  // Agregamos al arrelgo la materia
  profesores[profesor].push({
    id: cursos[index].id,
    materia: cursos[index].materia,
    nivel: cursos[index].nivel
  });
}

// Por cada "profesor" en el objeto
Object.keys(profesores).map(profesor => {
  // Guardamos en el storage
  let jsonData = JSON.stringify(profesores[profesor]);
  sessionStorage.setItem(profesor, jsonData);
});
```

Luego al llamar a la función `mostrar` y validar que el nombre del profesor existen en el `storage`, recuperamos el arreglo, lo recorremos y por cada curso creamos un elemento.

#### Ejemplo:

```
function mostrar() {
  let profesor = prompt('Introduce el nombre para ver su asignatura ');
  let value = sessionStorage.getItem(profesor);
  let cursos = value ? JSON.parse(value) : false;

  // Si no hay cursos
  if (!cursos) {
    alert("No has insertado ningun profesor, o profesor equivocado");
  } else {

    var content = document.getElementById('mostrar');
    content.innerHTML = '';
    // Por cada curso
    cursos.forEach(info => {
      // Creamos un elemento
      var divprofesor = document.createElement('div');
      var txtprofesor = document.createTextNode('Asignarua: ' + info.materia);

      divprofesor.appendChild(txtprofesor);
      // y lo agregamos al contenedor
      content.appendChild(divprofesor);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo conseguir resolver al final de otra forma, pero esta tambien es muy acertada muchas gracias.